# How to use the language neutral url alias pattern in pathauto?

Tags: 7, i18n-l10n, path-aliases

I want to use the following patterns in pathauto:

- myCT **All** languages: pattern1
- myCT **neutral** language: pattern2
- myCT **EN** language: pattern2

So that all neutral (UND) and EN nodes of myCT have pattern2 and all other languages have pattern1. I'm using the ALL languages pattern for all other, as I have many other languages that should have the same pattern and I do not want to repeat it.

I'm using entity translation module for myCT.

When I create a node and save it having the default language (UND) and automatic path alias, pattern1 is always generated. I have to **re-edit the node to have it get the correct pattern** (for UND/neutral language), pattern2.

First of all, the **pathauto_pattern_load_by_entity** function (pathauto.module file) is called before the node creation, so the language of the node is always UND during creation of a node.

Second, trying to debug the pathauto module I can see the following:

```
function pathauto_pattern_load_by_entity($entity, $bundle = '', $language = LANGUAGE_NONE) {
  $patterns = &drupal_static(__FUNCTION__, array());

  $pattern_id = "$entity:$bundle:$language";
  if (!isset($patterns[$pattern_id])) {
    $variables = array();
    if ($language != LANGUAGE_NONE) {
      $variables[] = "pathauto_{$entity}_{$bundle}_{$language}_pattern";
    }
    if ($bundle) {
      $variables[] = "pathauto_{$entity}_{$bundle}_pattern";
    }
    $variables[] = "pathauto_{$entity}_pattern";

    foreach ($variables as $variable) {
      if ($pattern = trim(variable_get($variable, ''))) {
        break;
      }
    }

    $patterns[$pattern_id] = $pattern;
  }

  return $patterns[$pattern_id];
}
```

So in the following lines it seems that **it never takes into account the neutral language** path.

```
if ($language != LANGUAGE_NONE) {
   $variables[] = "pathauto_{$entity}_{$bundle}_{$language}_pattern";
}
```

Shouldn't that if statement be removed? How is it possible to use the neutral language path otherwise?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Good point, I was thinking the same too.

Rather then the line to be removed there should be a check for `LANGUAGE_NONE` to set a pattern in the variables array for "und"-language. Then if not set the language specific pattern in the array.

I opened an issue and posted a patch, please check out https://www.drupal.org/node/2438745

Comment: Thank you for the patch. I hope it get included in the next release of Pathauto.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [Pathauto i18n](https://www.drupal.org/project/pathauto_i18n) module:

> This module provides functionality to create aliases for each
>   language. Also this module will be helpful, if you use field
>   translation and you want show node on all language with paths,
>   different from node/nid.